# arrow with cross into chemfig

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, chemfig

was trying to make an arrow with a cross (when a chemical reaction does not occur) using tikz and chemfig, but the results were not good.

I would like to do something similar to the drawing below.

Any suggestion?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `chemfig` package already offers the `-/>` arrow type to denote non successful reactions. Based on its definition, I also defined a new `-x>` arrow type:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\catcode`\_=11
\definearrow5{-x>}{%
    \CF_arrowshiftnodes{#3}%
    \CF_expafter{\draw[}\CF_arrowcurrentstyle](\CF_arrowstartnode)--(\CF_arrowendnode)%
        coordinate[midway,shift=(\CF_ifempty{#4}{225}{#4}+\CF_arrowcurrentangle:\CF_ifempty{#5}{5pt}{#5})](line@start)%
        coordinate[midway,shift=(\CF_ifempty{#4}{45}{#4}+\CF_arrowcurrentangle:\CF_ifempty{#5}{5pt}{#5})](line@end)%
        coordinate[midway,shift=(\CF_ifempty{#4}{135}{#4}+\CF_arrowcurrentangle:\CF_ifempty{#5}{5pt}{#5})](line@start@i)%
        coordinate[midway,shift=(\CF_ifempty{#4}{315}{#4}+\CF_arrowcurrentangle:\CF_ifempty{#5}{5pt}{#5})](line@end@i);
    \draw(line@start)--(line@end);%
    \draw(line@start@i)--(line@end@i);%
    \CF_arrowdisplaylabel{#1}{0.5}+\CF_arrowstartnode{#2}{0.5}-\CF_arrowendnode
}
\catcode`\_=8

\begin{document}
\schemestart
A \arrow{-/>} B
\schemestop

\schemestart
A \arrow{-x>} B
\schemestop
\end{document}
```